# How can I show a card shadow on all sides?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have the following style

```
    card: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: 10,
      marginRight: Metrics.WIDTH*0.02,
      marginLeft: Metrics.WIDTH*0.02,
      borderColor: Colors.SILVER,
      borderWidth: 2,
      shadowColor: 'gray',
      shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 10,
    },
```

The above styles only create shadow on right and bottom. How to create showdow in all direction equally

[image]

Comment: It looks like the shadow is behaving exactly as a box-shadow should behave. It's supposed to be directional https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp

Comment: I see shadow at left and top. It's just not as wide due to your offset values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add multiple shadows in React-Native. But there is a workaround.

Set `width` and `height` of `shadowOffset` to zero, and try changing `shadowRadius` until you satisfy with the result.

```
  card:{
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height:0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 10,
}
```

Here is the result.

[image]